# Is there any record of group membership changes?

Tags: users

I followed [bad instructions](http://linuxservertutorials.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-add-user-to-group-in-linux.html) and left the `-a` out of:

```
usermod -a -G wireshark ak
```

Now all of my groups have been lost, including sudo permissions:

```
$ groups
ak wireshark
```

If I understand correctly, I should be able to fix this by booting to the recovery option in GRUB, but I'm not sure what groups need to be added back.

Where can I check to find out what groups I used to be in?

Comment: mine shows `adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare`. It might be a start to get it fixed.

Comment: once you are in the admin group you can add any other groups you need - look like this guy here had the same issue - http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2007/07/02/restore-default-ubuntu-groups/

Comment: put it in as an answer @fossfreedom and we can vote on it ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a standard Ubuntu installation there's a groups config backup file in `/var/backups/group.bak`. So (from a root recovery console) you could do something like

```
grep <your_username> /var/backups/group.bak
```

to list all groups you used to be in.

EDIT: as Lekensteyn rightly pointed out, it would be better to use the `/etc/group-` backup file, not the `/var/backups/group.bak` one.

Comment: The previous version is stored in `/etc/group-`. On my system, `/var/backups/group.bak` is the same as `/etc/group` which indicates that `/var/backups/group.bak` is really a backup of `/etc/group`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn: You're right. `group.bak` is (after a `cron.daily` job is run) the backup of `/etc/group`. The `/etc/group-` is a better option. I suggest you make your comment an answer.

Comment: your answer is nearly complete and remembered me on the existence of `/etc/group-`. Feel free to include my comment in your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

To recover you will need to boot from a live CD.

Mount the root partition (/).

e.g. if your root partition is on /dev/sda1

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Then edit the /etc/group file and add the admin group to yourself

```
cd /mnt/etc/
sudo nano group
```

find the admin group and add your user-id e.g. for me it would look like
`admin:x:121:fossfreedom`

Save and Reboot. You should be able to use sudo and su again.  You can then use Users and Groups to add in any groups you require:

[source](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2007/07/02/restore-default-ubuntu-groups/)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question of where I can check to find out what groups I used to be in.

Comment: @fossfreedom Excellent. Thanks, you just saved me a lot of time and headache. Due to my own stupidity I removed myself from admin group. Your solution above saved the day, and I learned quite a few things in the process.